# Dojox mobile swapview ontouchend is triggerred twice

Tags: dojo

With dojox mobile SwapView, when I swipe on Ipad 2 with iOS 6, the ontouchend function is triggerred before the end of the swipe and at the end. This bug makes the next view appearing and disapperain in a few milliseconds like a flash then the swipe is ok.

On iPad 3 with iOS 7 and on chrome I don't have this problem.

How to prevent this double call ?

Comment: Which Dojo version are you using ?

Comment: i'm using 1.9.2 and on 1.8.5 it was the same

Comment: actually any iPad and any ios versions have the same problem.I have found that the problem came from the opening of the keyboard on the form of the previous page. If the keyboard doesn't open I have no problem, but if it opens, ontouchend is triggerred twice when i swipe